# Clone only the .git directory of a git repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a repo in sync with google Drive, but I had the .git directory ignored so it is now uploaded to Google Drive.

Recently I formatted my `Gentoo` machine and after I had all Google Drive files synced again I realized the `.git` directory was not there.

The problem is I do not remember if I had some unstagged/uncommited changes in local not pushed to github.

I have been searching but I only found answers for the opposite question (Cloning without the `.git` directory)

- [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)
- [Cloning only a subdirectory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834386/cloning-only-a-subdirectory-with-git)
- [How to clone git repository only some directories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460885/how-to-clone-git-repository-only-some-directories)
- [Is it possible to clone only part of a git project?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233327/is-it-possible-to-clone-only-part-of-a-git-project)
- [Git Clone: Just the files, please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946538/git-clone-just-the-files-please)
- [Git clone without .git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497457/git-clone-without-git-directory)

I do not want to make a `git clone` of my repo until I am sure that possible local changes are not going to be loss.

Is there any way of cloning only the `.git` folder and then push any local changes that I may have in my machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solve it. It was an easy process:

1. I've cloned the repo to a different location eg (in `/tmp`)
2. I've copied the `.git` folder into my original repo folder
3. I did `git status` on my original repo folder and all the local changes were there.

Hope it helps others

Comment: the only issue w/ this method is that you haven't had a chance to checkout a specific branch and a default clone will have the 'master' branch checked out which isn't what you might be wanting to compare your local file set against

Comment: Since you just need the .git folder and not the whole working directory, make sure that you clone it using --bare option.

Comment: @EissaN. With `--bare` option remote-tracking branches are not created, so you can't push and compare against them.

Answer (score 33):

The one-step solution would be:

```
git clone --no-checkout <repo_url>
```

or if you already have an empty dir for it,

```
cd myrepo
git clone --no-checkout <repo_url> .
```

Comment: Or `git clone --no-checkout <repo_url> myrepo` =)

Comment: what if your directory is not empty?

Comment: If your directory is not empty, git won't do the clone. But if you want what's in the directory, just clone into an empty directory and then copy the files you had into the directory where you cloned.

Comment: It doesn't restore the index, so if you just move the `.git` directory into the working tree `git status` output will be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

As has been said in another answer, there is a `--no-checkout` option of `git clone` command, but it's not a direct or complete solution to the problem in question:

1. it refuses to clone into non-empty directory;
2. it doesn't restore the index (as there should be no files in a directory).

So if you'll just move the `.git` directory into your working tree and run `git status` you'll get an incorrect result:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
        deleted:    Home.rest

Untracked files:
        Home.rest
```

---

With that being said, there are two ways to solve the problem:

- Clone using temporary directory:

  ```
  $ git clone -n <repo_url> tmp
  $ mv tmp/.git/ . && rm -d tmp
  $ git read-tree HEAD
  ```
- Imitate clone in existing directory with a working tree:

  ```
  $ git init
  $ git remote add -m master -f origin <repo_url>
  $ git reset refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
  $ git branch -u origin
  ```

If there are more people working with the same repository (there are some remote changes as well), you'll be having a hard time [figuring out which state your local repository was in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49059767/11725753).

On the other hand, if you're sure there are no local changes it's easier to simply delete your working tree and make a full clone:

```
$ rm -rf <local_repo_dir>
$ git clone <repo_url> <local_repo_dir>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Do a `git clone` to a different folder on your machine from your online repo
2. Checkout the branch that you're interested in comparing your local files against.
3. Then copy/paste your folders contents over top the new clone.
4. Check to see whats changed (if anything and commit as you would).

Comment: Actually I solve it right now xD. I've cloned the repo to a diiferent directoty and copied the `.git` directory. Everything is ok now!

Comment: Should I remove my question or post an answer to my Question?

Comment: @algui91: Because there is an up-voted answer, you can't delete the question.  You may choose to post your self-answer though there will be a delay (a couple of days, I think) before you can mark it accepted.  OTOH, what you say you did closely matches what this answer suggests; you should probably just accept this answer.

Comment: Yes, two days. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if I have a directory named `local_directory`, I create a new repository in github named `remote_local_directory`. I want to push local_directory to remote_directory.

I use these commands

```sh
git clone --bare ${remote_directory}.git local_directory/.git
cd local_directory
git init
git add .
git commit
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

`git clone --bare` only clone `.git` directory
and `git init` will reinitialize local repository

use other git commands like local repository is related to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is a fresh `.git` directory without any changes to files, so you can do `git status` and see if anything was changed.

Expecting your `pwd` is your project directory with an old `.git` directory that has the `origin` for the repository set up, you could run the following command:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/tmp/_delme \
    && git clone --no-checkout `cat .git/config | grep url | awk -F' = ' '{print $2}'` /var/www/tmp/_delme \
    && rm -rf .git \
    && mv /var/www/tmp/_delme/.git . \
    && git add -A
    && rm -rf /var/www/tmp/_delme
```